# jquery dropdown not working with angular js

Tags: jquery, angularjs, dropdown

I am new in angularjs,My dropdown(for logout) is not working, I tried with jquery conflict node but nothing happen,i just want whenever i click on button then drodown should appear.Here is my code

```
<button class="dropdown-toggle user-profile hidden-xs"  type="button"
        data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="true">
    <img class="img-circle" src="{{pic || 'img/final_placeholder.png'}}"
         width="24px" height="24px" style="object-fit:cover;">
    <span class="caret"></span>
</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are using bootstrap, then you should add the `id` to the button. This id should match to the attribute `aria-labelledby`

With reference from your code:

```
<div class="dropdown">
  <button class="btn btn-secondary dropdown-toggle user-profile hidden-xs" type="button" id="logoutButton" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
    <img class="img-circle" src="{{pic || 'img/final_placeholder.png'}}"
     width="24px" height="24px" style="object-fit:cover;">
<span class="caret"></span>
  </button>
  <div class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="logoutButton">
    <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Log Out</a>
  </div>
</div>
```

Hope that helps!